# jquery ajax "readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot

I am trying to send a GET request through AJAX (jquery) to a spring boot server. The program is working fine on eclipse inbuilt web browser but not in chrome/firefox. It gives error {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}.

HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var q = 0;

        $(function () {

            $("input[name='type']").click(function () {
                q = $("[name='type']:checked").val();
            });

            $("#btn").click(function () {

                t = $("#in").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    dataType: "text",
                    url: "http://localhost:9001/doubleit?data=" + t + "&type=" + q,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert('we have trouble ' + JSON.stringify(e));
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="in"/>
    double it<input type="radio" name="type" value="2"/>
    triple it<input type="radio" name="type" value="3"/>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="btn"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Spring Boot Code:

```
package jqrywithjava;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    @RestController
    public class DoubleitController {

        @GetMapping("/doubleit")
        public int nobodyCares(@RequestParam("data") int pqr, @RequestParam("type") int xyz) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            return pqr * xyz;
        }

    }
```

and

```
package jqrywithjava;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Please help me make this work in chrome or firefox.

Comment: did you got any error ?

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax request you are using `dataType:'text'`, From [jQuery’s Ajax-Related Methods](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/) description

```
// The type of data we expect back
    dataType : "text",
```

Update your ajax to

```
$.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "http://localhost:9001/doubleit?data=" + t + "&type=" + q,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert('we have trouble ' + JSON.stringify(e));
        }
});
```

Then add `@ResponseBody` to the controller method and return your result as String from there.

```
@GetMapping("/doubleit")
@ResponseBody
public String nobodyCares(@RequestParam("data") int pqr, @RequestParam("type") int xyz) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    Integer result = pqr * xyz;
    return Integer.toString(result);
}
```